# Dealing with two unique values in SQL

Tags: sql, variables, unique

I am working with a table right now that has two variables - HouseholdID and DonationID. I want to count the number of unique households per donation, so I want to somehow filter my table so that I only have the results for the FIRST time a household donated to a fund.

[image]

In this^ case, I would want to filter the results to have the first Jones donation to the cancer fund, the Jones donation to the Ronald McDonald Fund, and the Smith donation to the Ronald McDonald fund. How can you specify this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You an use aggregation:

```
select household, donation, min(date)
from donations
group by household, donation;
```

If you have additional columns on the table, then filtering -- using either a correlated subquery or `row_number()` -- is appropriate:

```
select d.*
from donations d
where d.date = (select min(d2.date)
                from donations d2
                where d2.household = d.household and d2.donation = d.donation
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just looking for the unique count:

```
select Donation, count(distinct Household) as Households from donations group by Donation
```